# Unexpected output with global variable and property variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I run the following program, I get `Sum = 0`. But if I move he statements `int a = 5` and `int b = 6 inside -(int)sum {...}`, I get the output as 11. I certainly understand why I get the correct solution in the second case. But why do I get `Sum = 0` when I define global variables with the same name as `@property` variables? Does the compiler give higher priority to `@property` variables over global variable?

// newFunction.h:

```
@interface newFunction : NSObject

@property int a,b;
-(int)sum;

@end
```

// newFunction.m

```
@implementation newFunction

@synthesize a,b;

int a = 5;
int b = 6;

-(int)sum
{
    return (a+b);
}

@end
```

//main.m

```
@autoreleasepool {

        newFunction *var1 = [[newFunction alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Sum = %i", [var1 sum]);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these are not global variables. These are instance variables. Second - yes, the compiler gives higher priority to the variables defined by @synthesize.